# Is there a way of suppressing the dialog asking if you want to save on a specific file?

Tags: vsix, visual-studio-addins, vsx, vspackage, vs-extensibility

When a user double clicks an item in one of my files, it opens a temporary file for them to edit using DTE. Once they are done editing that temporary file they close it and it adds to the parent file. That works great.

My issue is, is that when they go to close the temporary file, it asks them if they want to save. In this situation clicking no is the right thing to do else it asks you to save the file as something. Is there a way of changing this so that it doesn't ask the user and always just closes the file without saving it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

While the DTE methods don't expose a way to do this, you could leverage IVsUIShellOpenDocument instead, and then explicitly add the RDT_DontSave, RDT_DontSaveAs, and potentially the RDT_DontAddtoMRU flags, via the grfOpenStandard argument passed to IVsUIShellOpenDocument.OpenStandardEditor or similar.

Alternatively, you could use [IVsRunningDocumentTable.ModifyDocumentFlags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsrunningdocumenttable.modifydocumentflags.aspx) to add the flags after the fact.

But for that, you'll need to retrieve the document cookie with something like [IVsRunningDocumentTable2.FindAndLockDocumentEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsrunningdocumenttable2.findandlockdocumentex.aspx).